# How can I show a component after item clicked in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So to make things clear and simple :
I  have an **AddUser** Component to be shown on my **AdminDash** component after clicking my Add User **Item**, everything is shown on my AdminDash,
My **AdminDash** contains a **SideMenu**, **SideMenu** contains **Items**, **Items** contains list of **Item**
let me show you the tree :

1. AddUser.
2. AdminDash:

   - SideMenu:

     - Items:

       1. Item.
       2. Item.
       3. Item.

**AdminDash**

```
//Some code
<SideMenu />
//Here where I want to show my addUser Component
```

**SideMenu**

```
//Some code
<Items />
```

**Items**

```
//Some code
<Item Name="addUser" />
<Item Name="deleteUser" />
<Item Name="updateUser" />
```

**Item**

```
<ul>
  <li   
onClick={I WANT TO SHOW MY ADDUSER COMPONENT}
>
    <div> {props.Name} </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**AddUser**

```
//Some random code 
<p> this is the add user component</p>
```

So whenever I click an item like AddUser I want its component to show on my Admin Dash, any hint?

Comment: Can you share a more complete and comprehensive code example showing the complete `AdminDash` component all that it's rendering so we can see how these components related and render? Basically you just need some state in a common ancestor that is updated by a child/descendent component that is used to conditionally render the content you want. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: @DrewReese `AdminDash` has nothing but a navBar and this SideMenu so basically it's an empty component that contains a top navBar and a left Menu.

Comment: So "//Here where I want to show my addUser Component", is that relevant for what you are trying to accomplish? Is that all you've tried so far?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried to pass my onclick function as props from my item utill my SlideMenu but it didn't work, there is a solution of making my AddUser on its own page, I mean whenever I click on add user it redirect me to a new page /adduser, but I want to see if there's a possibility to show it on my page( `adminDash`) without the need of redirecting...

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following, but why can't you render `<AddUser />` in the `AdminDash` where the `//Here where I want to show my addUser Component` comment is?

Comment: @DrewReese because it has to be clicked on first, AdminDash is component that has a sideMenu which contains AddUser, RemoveUser, UpdateUser buttons, so it's all about when I click a button I want to render that AddUser or RemoveUser...

Comment: Ok, so it seems my suggestion from my first comment still stands. You need some state in a common ancestor holding the state for what should be displayed, and pass down as props the state and a callback to update the state to the relevant children. Would you like a rudimentary demo? In the meantime, can you share what you've tried as part of a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a very many tries and long researches, I almost used useContext to do the job, but finally I found the solution, these are the steps :

1. First I added a new component `<AdminOptions />` which contains all the logic of rendering my `<AddUser />` and `<DeleteUser />` and `<UpdateUsers />` .
2. I Passed a function through the last child ( `<Item />` ) to call it and pass some parameters with, to the parent component which is `<AdminDash />` to tell which item is clicked and which to render.
3. Then I used these parameters and pass them again to my new component ` to render that specific item, it's a bit complex and many hierarchy but it's a perfect solution for me.

***AdminDash***

```
const[componentId, setComponentId]= React.useState(false);
const [show, setShowComponent] = React.useState(false);

const handleClick=(id)=>{
      if(id===componentId){
        setShowComponent(!show);
      }
      else{
        setComponentId(id);
        setShowComponent(true);
      }
    }
return (
//Here I pass the handleClick hooks to the childs
<SideMenu handleClick={handleClick} />
//my new component who will render the items component
<AdminOptions whatToShow={componentId} show={show}  />
);
```

***SideMenu***

```
//passing again the handleClick to childs
<Items handleClick={props.handleClick} />
```

***Items***

```
//I'm passing again the handleClick and giving each item an ID to differentiate between them 
<Item 
  Name="addUser"
  Id="AddUser"
  handleClick={props.handleClick} />
<Item 
  Name="deleteUser"
  Id="DeleteUser"
  handleClick={props.handleClick} />
<Item 
  Name="updateUser"
  Id="UpdateUser"
  handleClick={props.handleClick} />
```

***Item***

```
<ul>
//here in the onClick i pass the function handleclick with an item id as a parameter
  <li   
onClick={()=>{props.handleClick(props.Id)}}
>
    <div> {props.Name} </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***AdminOptions***

```
//So here is a switch case conditional rendering depending on Item's ID
switch (props.whatToShow){
            case "AddUser":
                return(props.show && <AddUser />);
            case "DeleteUser":
                return(props.show && <DeleteUser />);
            case "UpdateUser":
                return(props.show && <UpdateUser />);
            default :
                return (<> </>);
```

So when I click on Add user item it pass an Id of that specific Item to the parent component(AdminDash) which execute that handleClick with the Id of the item, and make the AdminOptions Show that item Component in the AdminDash,
I did my best to make it as clear as possible, anyone who has a question leave it in the comment.